# Realizar dos consultas en un mismo metodo en Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, sql

En una aplicación hecha con Laravel, tengo los siguientes metodos:

```
public function scopeGetCountAndSumCotizacionesByVendedor($query, $ano, $mes)
{        
    return $query->select('trabajada_por', DB::raw('COUNT("trabajada_por") as cant_vendedor'), DB::raw('SUM("monto") as total'))
                    ->where('nombre_status', 'LIKE' ,'COT%')
                    ->where('borrado', 0)
                    ->whereYear('fecha_recibido', $ano)
                    ->whereMonth('fecha_recibido', $mes)
                    ->groupBy('trabajada_por')
                    ->get();
}
public function scopeGetCountAndSumCotizacionesByVendedorByTemporada($query, $ano, $mes_desde, $mes_hasta)
{        
    return $query->select('trabajada_por', DB::raw('COUNT("trabajada_por") as cant_vendedor'), DB::raw('SUM("monto") as total'))
                    ->where('nombre_status', 'LIKE' ,'COT%')
                    ->where('borrado', 0)
                    ->whereYear('fecha_recibido', $ano)
                    ->whereMonth('fecha_recibido', '>=', $mes_desde)
                    ->whereMonth('fecha_recibido', '<=', $mes_hasta)
                    ->groupBy('trabajada_por')
                    ->get(); 
}
```

Y los llamo desde el controlador:

Llamo al método cuando solo necesito los datos de un solo mes.

```
$cotizacionesCantPorVendedor = Cotizaciones::getCountAndSumCotizacionesByVendedor($ano, $mes);
```

Llamo a este otro método cuando tengo que traer datos entre un rango de meses.

```
$cotizacionesCantPorVendedorPorTemporada = Cotizaciones::getCountAndSumCotizacionesAByVendedorByTemporada($ano, $mes_desde, $mes_hasta);
```

Como pueden ver, la mayoría del cuerpo de los métodos son iguales, solo cambia el `whereMonth` por el rango de meses o un mes en particular. Me gustaría saber si se puede realizar estas mismas consultas en un solo método de la forma mas limpia posible, así no usar dos métodos distintos y poder ahorrar mucho más código.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public function scopeGetCountAndSumCotizacionesByVendedorByTemporada($query, $ano, $mes_desde, $mes_hasta)
{
        return $query
            ->select('trabajada_por', DB::raw('COUNT("trabajada_por") as cant_vendedor'), DB::raw('SUM("monto") as total'))
            ->where('nombre_status', 'LIKE', 'COT%')
            ->where('borrado', 0)
            ->whereYear('fecha_recibido', $ano)
            ->whereBetween('fecha_recibido', [$mes_desde, $mes_hasta])
            ->groupBy('trabajada_por')
            ->get();
}
```

Le pasas en $mes_desde el mes de inicio y $mes_hasta el mes final, y cuando quieras solo un mes le pasas el mismo mes en cada variable